# how to connect a php file chooser, upload button using android studio

Tags: php, android, filechooser

here is my **java** code for

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity3);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.adk.comuf.com/1.php");
    // Other webview options
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //Other webview settings
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
}
```

here is my **php** code

the php filechoose button is nit working inside the app the tool is android studio.

Comment: There is no php code...

Comment: A php filechoose button? What would that be? What has this to do with Android Studio?